# Simulating NMOS as capacitor example

Tags: capacitor, analog, design, cadence, varactor

I would like to ask your opinion regarding NMOS test-bench as a varactor (voltage control capacitor). I am trying to find the properties of Vg,W for achieving a \$200fF\$ capacitor.

Here is my test-bench : 
[image]

Calculated \$C\$ using AC analysis, where

\$C = \frac{I}{(V*2*pi*f)}\$

\$I = NMOS-Gate\$ point

and

\$V = voltage\$ on gate net.

Is this correct?

**question** - we are looking for \$Cgs\$ here, so can I just take the value from Cadence "Results Browser"?

Comment: Don't forget that you need to add DC beside the AC voltage, for a proper `.op` point and `.AC` analysis. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/498912/95619) for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the equivalent circuit model of a FET. Disconsidering the parasitic inductances, if the drain and source ends are short citcuited the equivalent gate capacitance is given by:

$$C_{G}=C_{GS}+C_{GD}$$

[image: model]

[source](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/mosfet.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015357444e913f4f)

The gate capacitance can be calculated by connecting a gate resistance much bigger than \$R_G\$ and sweeping the AC gate voltage according to the following e.g.:

1. Sweep AC gate voltage
2. Find the frequency at which the amplitude drops by 3dB
3. Workout the gate capacitance

In this case, the gate capacitance is given by:

$$C_{G(CALC)}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi\cdot23.4963kHz\cdot1k\Omega}\approx 6.77nF$$

It can be double checked by inspecting the model details:

$$C_{G(MODEL)}=5.2nF + 1.6nF=6.8nF$$

[image: circuit_2]

Comment: I did not understand few things : 1. you did not sweep the AC voltage, it is constant 1V according to your simulation, so where does Vac of the gate plays a part ? 2. why you took the 3dB point ? 3. according to your answer, it is much easier to take the model Cgs+Cgd capacitance as Cg other then calculate from simulation - is that right ?

Comment: 1. It is actually being swept with the instruction `.ac dec 1000 100 1e6`. The 1V is the DC bias. 2. You are right provided that you have such information in a model and parasitics are not accounted for. Furthermore, this is a very simple model. However, in your case, if you dont have such information at hand, you have to extract them by either simulation or calculation, or a combination of both.

Comment: While the AC voltage is 1 V, what is swept is the AC Frequency