# Plotting small signal \$i_d\$ of a NMOS in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to perform a transient simulation and plot the drain current of an NMOS for different values of VGS (DC bias).

My schematic looks something like this:

[image]

Now, the drain current consists of both AC and DC components. I wanted to know a way to plot only the AC component of drain current (\$i_d\$):

$$I_d = I_D + i_d.$$

I can manually subtract the DC drain current (at operating point) from the total current to get \$i_d\$ and add a trace, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use the AC voltage amplitude property of the source and run an .ac analysis.

Comment: Small signal means `.AC` analysis, use a single voltage source with `{DC} ac 1` as value, where `{DC}` is the DC level (defined as a `.param` or directly as a numerical value). Also see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/498912/95619), very similar.